# Нужно ли обособлять "действительно" в данном контексте?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, невыделение-вводных

> Педагоги школы Ли Страсберга проводят тренинги, благодаря которым,
>   действительно, эмоции способны возникать у актёра по команде.

Comment: У актёра по команде? У актёра по команде «Стой!» слетела фуражка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Педагоги школы Ли Страсберга проводят тренинги, благодаря которым  эмоции действительно способны возникать у актёра по команде.**

Слово ***действительно*** желательно считать вводным, когда оно подтверждает/доказывает сказанное ранее. В остальных случаях - это наречие со значением соответствия действительности.